# Conditions for existence of smallest set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a set of sets closed under countable intersections. Is this enough to guarantee that $\mathcal{S}$ contains a smallest element?

In my particular case of interest, $\mathcal{S}$ is a set of compact sets in the complex plane.

My feeling is that it should be possible to construct a minimising sequence $s_1 \supseteq s_2 \supseteq s_3 \supseteq \ldots$ and then conclude that $\bigcap_{i = 1}^\infty s_i$ is the smallest set, but I don't know how to set up this sequence.

Comment: You mean a minimal element, not a minimum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For compact subsets in the plane, countable sequences suffice. This is because there cannot be any uncountable properly decreasing sequences of closed sets in Euclidean spaces. Given that, construct a minimal element as follows. Suppose there is no minimal element. Then pick any $K_0$. It cannot be minimal so there is some $K_1 \subsetneq K_0$. Continue this way by recursion: if we have $K_\alpha$ it's not minimal by assumption so we have $K_{\alpha+1} \subsetneq K_\alpha$. And for countable limit ordinals $\alpha$, having found $K_\beta$ for all $\beta < \alpha$ we just define $K_\alpha = \cap \{K_\beta: \beta < \alpha\}$. We continue until $\omega_1$, and we thus construct $K_\alpha$ for all $\alpha < \omega_1$ such that $K_\gamma \subsetneq K_\delta$ for $\delta < \gamma < \omega_1$. But such sequences cannot exist in second countable spaces, so contradiction. There must be some minimal element where the process stops.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $\Omega$ denote the first uncountable ordinal, and let your
sets in $\mathcal S$ be those of the form $S_\alpha=\{\xi:\alpha\le\xi<\Omega\}$ where $\alpha<\Omega$. The intersection of a countable sequence $(S_{\alpha_i})$
is $S_\beta$ where $\beta=\sup_i\alpha_i$. Note that $\beta<\Omega$.
So $\mathcal S$ is closed under countable intersections, yet has
no minimal element.

Comment: Suppose $S$ is a subset of the power set of $\mathbb R^n$, for example, then would the above hold true? I don't know the theory of ordinals, so I'm just curious to know if you need to go to such lengths to find a counter example.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг You can embed $\Omega$ in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't know that, so thank you. So the question is then, can we give a more concrete example than this one, where possibly $S$ can be described more explicitly than above, because I don't know what $\alpha < \Omega$ means when both are ordinals, although we know what it means when they are real numbers/

Comment: Also, is there a way to avoid this pathological case? I am particularly interested in $\mathcal{S}$ being a particular set of compact sets in the complex plane.

Comment: @gTcV So why didn't you say so?

Comment: Because I didn't know it was relevant, and I have a preference for questions which are as general as possible so they help as many people as possible.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown you cannot embed $\Omega$ into $\mathbb{R}$ of course... for lots of reasons: it's not second countable,  e.g.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Oh yes I can! You do know that $\Bbb R$ is uncountable, don't you? $\smile$

Comment: Yes, but you cannot embed it qua order or topology. @LordSharktheUnknown

Answer (score 0):

Let $\beta$ be the first uncountable ordinal, and $S$ the set of intervals $[\alpha, \beta]$ for ordinals $\alpha < \beta$.